# I have to change columns of table into rows and all headings as well as all partitions

Tags: tables, tabularx

[image]

Here is my table and I want to change rows column i.e., all heading which is written in the column and same division of columns into rows. Kindly help me out.

```
\begin{table*}
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|}
\hline
t&\multicolumn{3}{c}{SH}&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{SH}&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{MH }&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{MH}\\ \cline{2-13}
           &&&Difference&&Difference&&&Difference&&&Differences\\ \cline{2-13}
Unschedule     &5.01  & ---    &---& 5.01&--- &---&22.46&---&---& 24.54  &--- &\\
            &4.31  &13.97\%&0.7&4.68&6.58\%&0.33&12.78 &43.09\%&11.78 &13.92&43.27\%&10.62\\
            &3.24  &35.32\%&1.77&3.48&30.53\%&1.53&14.70&34.55\%&9.84&12.98&47.10\%&11.56\\
             &3.73  &25.54\%&1.28&3.64 &27.34\%&1.37&12.70&43.45\%&11.48&14.01&42.66\%&10.53\\
           &3.09  &38.32\%&1.92&3.13 &37.52\%& 1.88&11.73&47.77\%&12.78&12.01&50.08\%&12.53\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you mean you want to swap rows and columns?

Comment: yes! and instead of partitions in columns as shown in 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th columns it should be in rows in 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th columns.

Comment: Could you post a complete code?

Comment: I have posted bernard!

Comment: That's not a *full* compilable code. Are you in two-column mode?

Comment: It is full code except missing documents and end documents. I'm using 6 columns and with four rows and their partitions.

Comment: What's your preamble? Also I was asking whether the *document* was in two-column, not the table (the reason is the `table*` environment that you use).

Comment: what about simple rewrote your table (yourself) from scratch?

Comment: Please answer my question in the given link. Bernad Zarko https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379780/question-related-to-previous-answers

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it. I replaced most of the `p{1cm}` columns with `S` columns, from `siunitx` to ensure column alignments on the decimal dot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow, siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering\sisetup{table-format=2.2, table-space-text-post = {\,\%}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|*{5}{S|}}
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{t} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Unschedule}\\[2pt]
 \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{SH} & & 5.01 &4.31 & 3.24 & 3.73 &3.09 \\
 & & {—} &13.97 \,\% &35.32 \,\% &25.54 \,\% &38.32 \,\% \\
& Difference & {—} & 0.7 & 1.77 &1.28 &1.92 \\
 \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{SH} & & 5.01 &4.68 & 3.48 &3.64 &3.13 \\
 & & {—} & 6.58 \,\% & 30.53 \,\% &27.34 \,\% &37.52 \,\% \\
  & Difference & {—} &0.33 &1.53 &1.37 & 1.88 \\
 \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{MH} & &22.46 &12.78 &14.70 & 12.70 &11.73 \\
  & & {—} & 43.09 \,\% & 34.55 \,\% & 43.45 \,\% & 47.77 \,\% \\
 & Difference & {—} & 11.78 & 9.84 &11.48 &12.78 \\
 \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{MH} & & 24.54 & 13.92 & 12.98 & 14.01 & 12.01 \\
 & & {—} & 43.27 \,\% & 47.10 \,\% & 42.66\, \% & 50.08 \,\% \\
 & Difference & & 10.62 & 11.56 & 10.53 & 12.53 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]